# Заполнить массив из пяти любых имен с помощью prompt()

Tags: javascript

Циклом нужно заполнить массив с помощью команды prompt в котором будет список из 5-ти любых имен. Потом вывести с помощью prompt сообщение с просьбой ввести имя пользователя

Введенное имя, циклом сравнивать с именами в массиве. Если введенное имя пользователя не существует в массиве - выдавать с помощью alert() сообщение об ошибке. Если есть совпадение - выводить сообщение *"Андрей, вы успешно вошли"*.

Вместо *"Андрей"* должно быть имя текущего пользователя

Я набросал код, но он неполный и я не могу понять алгоритм действий.

```
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++);

var a = prompt("Enter your name");

if (a == arr) {
    alert( a + " вы успешно вошли! ");
} else{
    alert("Ошибка")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = ['Андрей','Петр','Алексей'],
        a = prompt("Enter your name"),
    i = 0;
while (i < arr.length) {
  if (a == arr[i]) {
    alert("Ошибка");
    return false;
  } else if(a !== arr[i] && i === (arr.length-1)){
    alert( a + " вы успешно вошли! ");
    arr.push(a);
    console.log(arr);
    return false;
  }
  i++;
}
```

в консоле после успешного добавления видно что в массив добавлен новый пользователь

Comment: спасибо,очень благодарен!

Comment: Немного не верно сразу написал, исправил))

Comment: та только начал изучать,штука не привычная,но чертовски интересная)еще раз спасибо))